# CodeIgniter not logging errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using IIS server and CodeIgniter. I added the full path of the log folder

```
$config['log_path'] = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/php/ci_applications/crud_one/logs/';
```

and threshold value as

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

My application folder path is

```
$application_folder = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php\ci_applications\crud_one';
```

> Given permission for that folder to write/modify for IIS_IUSRS.

Still CodeIgniter is not writing any logs.

My code for logging is

```
log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
```

Please help me in figuring out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Juts a note: For your log path `$config['log_path'] = FCPATH . 'ci_applications/application/crud_one/logs/'` make sure crud_one and logs writable

Comment: And application path `$application_folder = 'ci_applications/crud_one';`

Comment: I don't under stand your folder structure.